# "P2 publisher return code was 1" On fresh cloned WSO2 API Manager

Tags: java, maven, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm facing a challenging issue while attempting to build certain WSO2 products, specifically APIM (API Manager) versions. Previously, I was trying to fix CVE on APIM 3.2 and all was working fine, but recently I've encountered a persistent problem that has hindered my progress. Roughly a week ago, I noticed that my attempts to build Carbon or APIM products were consistently failing, even when using a freshly cloned repository with no modifications.

My development environment includes OpenJDK 11.0.20 and Maven 3.9.4 for building. However, despite these stable tools, I've run into an error that I'm unable to resolve on my own.

Here's a snippet from the log file of the API Manager 4.2.0 build:

```
[INFO] Command line:
    [/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java, -jar, /home/user/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/tycho/tycho-bundles-external/0.25.0/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20151021-1308.jar, -configuration, /tmp/tycho-p2-runtime3733042892252974600.tmp/configuration, -debug, -consoleLog, -console, -nosplash, -application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, -source, /home/user/INTM/Ticket40/apimtest/modules/p2-profile/product/target/tmp.1691598513211/featureExtract, -metadataRepository, file:/home/user/INTM/Ticket40/apimtest/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo, -metadataRepositoryName, am-p2-profile, -artifactRepository, file:/home/user/INTM/Ticket40/apimtest/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo, -artifactRepositoryName, am-p2-profile, -publishArtifacts, -publishArtifactRepository, -compress, -append]
Configuration location:
    file:/tmp/tycho-p2-runtime3733042892252974600.tmp/configuration/
Configuration file:
    file:/tmp/tycho-p2-runtime3733042892252974600.tmp/configuration/config.ini loaded
Install location:
    file:/tmp/tycho-p2-runtime3733042892252974600.tmp/
Framework located:
    file:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/tycho/tycho-bundles-external/0.25.0/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.0.v20160309-1913.jar
Framework classpath:
    file:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/tycho/tycho-bundles-external/0.25.0/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.0.v20160309-1913.jar
Debug options:
    file:/home/user/INTM/Ticket40/apimtest/modules/p2-profile/product/.options not found
Time to load bundles: 337
!SESSION 2023-08-09 18:28:43.789 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=11.0.20
java.vendor=Ubuntu
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=fr_FR
Framework arguments:  -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher -source /home/user/INTM/Ticket40/apimtest/modules/p2-profile/product/target/tmp.1691598513211/featureExtract -metadataRepository file:/home/user/INTM/Ticket40/apimtest/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo -metadataRepositoryName am-p2-profile -artifactRepository file:/home/user/INTM/Ticket40/apimtest/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo -artifactRepositoryName am-p2-profile -publishArtifacts -publishArtifactRepository -compress -append
Command-line arguments:  -debug -consoleLog -console -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher -source /home/user/INTM/Ticket40/apimtest/modules/p2-profile/product/target/tmp.1691598513211/featureExtract -metadataRepository file:/home/user/INTM/Ticket40/apimtest/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo -metadataRepositoryName am-p2-profile -artifactRepository file:/home/user/INTM/Ticket40/apimtest/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo -artifactRepositoryName am-p2-profile -publishArtifacts -publishArtifactRepository -compress -append

!ENTRY org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.impl 4 0 2023-08-09 18:28:44.644
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.impl [53]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.tycho

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1620)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1599)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.tycho.p2.maven.repository 4 0 2023-08-09 18:28:44.646
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.tycho.p2.maven.repository [54]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.tycho

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1620)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1599)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.tycho.p2.tools.impl 4 0 2023-08-09 18:28:44.646
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.tycho.p2.tools.impl [55]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.tycho

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1620)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1599)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2023-08-09 18:28:44.815
!MESSAGE Could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:239)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1516)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1489)
Starting application: 1028
Generating metadata for ..
Status ERROR: this code=0 publishing result null children=[Status OK: unknown code=0 OK null Status ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse code=0 An error occurred while publishing bundle /home/user/INTM/Ticket40/apimtest/modules/p2-profile/product/target/tmp.1691598513211/featureExtract/plugins/waffle-jna-1.6.0.wso2v7.jar: Invalid CEN header (invalid zip64 extra data field size) java.util.zip.ZipException: Invalid CEN header (invalid zip64 extra data field size) Status ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse code=0 An error occurred while publishing bundle /home/user/INTM/Ticket40/apimtest/modules/p2-profile/product/target/tmp.1691598513211/featureExtract/plugins/waffle-jna-1.6.0.wso2v6.jar: Invalid CEN header (invalid zip64 extra data field size) java.util.zip.ZipException: Invalid CEN header (invalid zip64 extra data field size)]
Product publisher application was executed with the following arguments:
-source
/home/user/INTM/Ticket40/apimtest/modules/p2-profile/product/target/tmp.1691598513211/featureExtract
-metadataRepository
file:/home/user/INTM/Ticket40/apimtest/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo
-metadataRepositoryName
am-p2-profile
-artifactRepository
file:/home/user/INTM/Ticket40/apimtest/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo
-artifactRepositoryName
am-p2-profile
-publishArtifacts
-publishArtifactRepository
-compress
-append
[ERROR] P2 publisher return code was 1
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: P2 publisher return code was 1
    at org.wso2.maven.p2.RepositoryGenMojo.generateRepository (RepositoryGenMojo.java:255)
    at org.wso2.maven.p2.RepositoryGenMojo.createRepo (RepositoryGenMojo.java:204)
    at org.wso2.maven.p2.RepositoryGenMojo.execute (RepositoryGenMojo.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for WSO2 API Manager - Aggregator Module 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Aggregator Module ............... SUCCESS [ 38.591 s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Styles Parent ................... SUCCESS [  0.025 s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Styles .......................... SUCCESS [ 22.109 s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - UI Styles ....................... SUCCESS [ 44.569 s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Multi Tenant Dashboard .......... SUCCESS [  3.821 s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Features Parent ................. SUCCESS [  0.022 s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Features Aggregator Module ...... SUCCESS [  0.019 s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Styles Features ................. SUCCESS [ 13.838 s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Multi Tenant Dashboard Feature .. SUCCESS [ 14.893 s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Secutity Aggregated Feature ..... SUCCESS [ 24.827 s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - P2 Profile Generation Parent .... SUCCESS [  0.018 s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - P2 Profile Generation ........... FAILURE [05:07 min]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - OAuth2 Grant Types .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - CallHome Module ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Identity Local Authenticators ... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Distribution Parent ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Distribution .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration Tests ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration Test Common Module .. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration Admin Clients Module  SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration Clients Module ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Publisher API client ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Admin API client ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Gateway API client ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Service Catalog API client ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Store API client ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Internal API client ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration Common Test Module .. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Test Artifacts Tests ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - RestFul Backend Module for Integration Tests SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - ArtifactDeploymentMonitor WebApp  SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Framework Extensions ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration Extensions Module ... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration UI Pages Module ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Extensions ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Third Party Key Manager ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration New Test Module ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Based on product backend Test Module SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Based on product benchmark Test Module SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Based on product restart Test Module SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  08:33 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-09T18:28:55+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wso2.maven:carbon-p2-plugin:5.1.2:p2-repo-gen (2-p2-repo-generation) on project am-p2-profile: P2 publisher return code was 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.wso2.maven:carbon-p2-plugin:5.1.2:p2-repo-gen (2-p2-repo-generation) on project am-p2-profile: P2 publisher return code was 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:333)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: P2 publisher return code was 1
    at org.wso2.maven.p2.RepositoryGenMojo.createRepo (RepositoryGenMojo.java:210)
    at org.wso2.maven.p2.RepositoryGenMojo.execute (RepositoryGenMojo.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: P2 publisher return code was 1
    at org.wso2.maven.p2.RepositoryGenMojo.generateRepository (RepositoryGenMojo.java:255)
    at org.wso2.maven.p2.RepositoryGenMojo.createRepo (RepositoryGenMojo.java:204)
    at org.wso2.maven.p2.RepositoryGenMojo.execute (RepositoryGenMojo.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :am-p2-profile
[DEBUG] Shutting down adapter factory; available factories [file-lock, rwlock-local, semaphore-local, noop]; available name mappers [discriminating, file-gav, file-hgav, file-static, gav, static]
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'file-lock' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'rwlock-local' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'semaphore-local' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'noop' factory
```

This error seems to be related to the P2 publisher process, where the return code is 1. I've tried investigating this further but haven't been able to identify the root cause. I've followed the recommended link provided in the error message, but I still couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I'm kindly requesting assistance from the community to help me diagnose and resolve this issue. If you need any additional information or specific details about my environment or configuration, please let me know. I'd be grateful for any insights or suggestions that can guide me towards resolving this build failure.

Thank you in advance for your support and expertise!

Comment: Could you try with an older version of JDK 11 (eg: 11.0.19)?

Comment: It seems to be working fine with 11.0.19 redhat build.
I already tried using JDK 17 and it didn't work so I thought it was not part of the problem.
Do you have any idea of why would that happen ?
Anyway thank you so much !
Have a great day.

Comment: I added the explanation as the answer

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of JDKs (for example 11.0.20+) introduced a change that affects older versions of certain dependencies. JDK has introduced a system property [1] that can be used to overcome this at runtime. APIM builds are also affected by this change in JDK. So, you will have to use an older version of JDK until those dependencies are bumped.

Furthermore, building product repos with JDK 17 is not support yet.

[1] - https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8302992

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue.
The build fails with jdk11.0.20+8 but works with jdk-11.0.20.1+1.
I didn't tried with older jdk versions such as 11.0.19

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).